# Add a Custom Toolbar with buttons when Addin is installed

Tags: vba, excel, toolbar

I explain you my problem.
I created an excell addin with a lot o useful functions.

I passed it to my colleagues that use it every day.

Now I want that when the add in is istalled on thei PC a custom toolbar with buttons created by me is also added to their excel permanently.

Is such thing possible? If it is could you please point me in the right direction?

thank you very much for your help

Comment: Which version of Excel will the add-in be installed to? There are 2 methods and they are ***very*** different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I use excel 2013

Comment: Ah, OK. Since Office went 'Open'  (after 2003) all menu/button creation switched from programmatic to embedded. You will want to research/Google `custom Excel ribbon`. A massive topic and one that wouldn't fit in an answerbox here. Good luck!

Comment: Create a Custom Excel Ribbon as CLR mentioned above in your addin file. You can use this tool (free): http://www.andypope.info/vba/ribboneditor.htm. Information about callbacks can be found here: http://www.accessribbon.de/en/